# Delphi TRichEdit page setup

Tags: delphi, trichedit, page-setup

I have an RTF document with defined page settings:

```
(...}\paperw16840\paperh11907\margl794\margt709\margr794\margb983\viewkind4\\uc1\trowd\....)
```

In my app I use a `TRichEdit` to show the document.

The `TRichEdit` has a `TPanel` as its `Parent`, and is using `Align=alClient` and `AlignWithMargins=True`.

I set the Panel's `Width` to `16840 * PixelsPerInch/1440` (1123 pixels) and I see that is equal to the page's width, as shown in MSWord (scale=100%).

Setting the RichEdit's `Margins` to `794 * PixelsPerInch/1440` (53 pixels), the `Width` of the RichEdit is smaller than it must be, or the margins are bigger than they must be (compared with MSWord).

No borders, no other margins, except what I set in code:

```
function pixelsOf(prop : string) : integer;
var
  i,j,l : integer;
begin
  result := -1;
  l := length(prop);
  i := pos(prop,s);
  if i > 0 then begin
    j := i+l;
    while s[j] in ['0'..'9'] do inc(j);
    result := round(strToIntDef(copy(s,i+l,j-i-l),-1)*PixelsPerInch/1440);
  end;
end;
```

```
paperW := pixelsOf('\paperw'); // pixelsOf() calcs twips*pixelsPerInch/1440
PanelPreview.Width := paperW; 
Lm := pixelsOf('\margl'); 
RichEdit1.Margins.Left := Lm; 
Rm := pixelsOf('\margr'); 
RichEdit1.Margins.Right := Rm; 
Tm := pixelsOf('\margt');   
RichEdit1.Margins.Top := Tm;
```

The value of `paperW` gives the correct Panel width (compared with MSWord), but the values of `Lm` and `Rm` give bigger margins, so the RichEdit becomes narrower.

How can I calculate the correct margins so the RichEdit has the same layout as MSWord?

This maybe helps. I noticed that :

1. `TRichedit` leaves a space about 10 pixels at the left side (the rendering is starting after this space). Is there a parameter that can be fix this other than margins.left ?
2. `TRichedit`doesn't render any table wider than its width (MSword do
   this adjusting the margins). So the TRichedit trancates everything
   outside its margins.

The result of the above is that the left margin seems wider than must be and truncates the right side of the table if it is winder.

see the image [image]

Comment: Can you please format your question?

Comment: You must take into account border width and margin values of both the panel and the TRichEditControl. At the end of the day you want the *clientWidth* property of your *TRichEditControl* to be the value you are trying to achieve, not the *width* of the *parent control*.

Comment: Please add this information to your question. It is important.

Comment: I think we need to see your pixelsOf function too. Clearly you are using VCL (because it is a TRichEdit) so width etc. of type integer. Depending on your calculation there will almost certainly be rounding errors. Realistically you need to round paperW up and the others down. Since you are using the same function for both, you are not really going to be able to do that.

Comment: The difference is more than 20 pixels. So it isn't rounding error.
The function  pixelsOf just finds the arithetic part of the property (eg \paperw16840) and gives the round(Twips*pixelsPerInch/1440)